# Mobile UI Controls in CSS alone or minimal JS?

Tags: css, html, web-applications, mobile

Any good frameworks out there for Buttons/Lists/Searchboxes etc, the usual controls expected from a mobile app/web in CSS alone or minimal JS?

I've been using JQeuryMobile, Sencha etc etc but they feel heavy, specially on lower end handsets.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for not wanting to use jQuery Mobile. It's so bloated and full of crap that my lowly Galaxy Europa melts every time I visit a site using it!

Comment: I've started working on one myself, but like I've said - ITS VERY BASIC! Just a look and feel thing NO functionality which I really think is best done with xui/zepto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[iUI](http://www.iui-js.org/about) is made to look like a native iPhone app - but it is described on its site as " lightweight as can be" and contrasts itself with JQuery Mobile

http://www.iui-js.org/about

Comment: It is minimal as per my request but - I've elected to do my stylying via straight up CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that jQueryMobile is heavy —specially considering all its capability— You may want to review the way you app is built and introduce app-specific optimization such us:

- Simplify the app (show only what you need for mobile)
- Minimize Application and Data Size
- Aggregate Images into a Single Composite Resource (Sprites)
- Include Background Images Inline in CSS Style Sheets
- Keep DOM Size Reasonable  6. Ensure Paragraph Text Flows
- Avoid Redirects